# grabbing text between two anchor words using jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, text

I'm retrieving data from a form, using Jquery's ajax method. The data is coming back fine, and I can retrieve individual div elements by id or class.

My problem is this - within one div I want to retrieve specific text occuring between two constant anchor words; this text occurs right at the start of the div. I've created a string with all the text from the div, and I'm guessing that I can approach it in either of two ways. The first would be to run a `.match()` with a correct regular expression, or alternatively run a `.replace()` to delete all text after the end anchor word.
I'm stumped for the format of the regular expression though - or perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way?

So, for example:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Your Results</h2>");
    $(data).find('.Status').appendTo('#message');
   toreplace= $(data).find('.Results').text();

  textresult = toreplace.match();
  $('#message').append(textresult);
}
```

The text in question looks like this

**Results** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Fusce iaculis ullamcorper egestas.
 Sed congue imperdiet sem et interdum.
 
Aliquam erat volutpat.
 Nulla facilisi.
 Duis in nisi arcu, non ullamcorper nulla.
 
**Sed** vel est vitae nunc volutpat ullamcorper.
 
Quisque semper fermentum quam ac dapibus. Quisque orci augue, cursus et dignissim nec, consequat non metus.

So I want to grab all the text between 'Results' and 'Sed'.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regex `Results(.*)Sed` would help you, but in JS, dot, does'nt match newlines, so before parsing text for occurances, you must replace `\r\n` by something (that you wold replace back to \r\n in future) or just delete occurances of \r\n.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a string split:

```
var txt = $('.post-text').html().split("<strong>Results</strong>")
var txt1= txt[1].split("<strong>Sed</strong>")
var result = txt1[0]
```